# Jest Error expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected) while unit testing auth.middleware.js file

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I tried to figure out why the test fails for the auth.middleware.js file. But, unable to find the cause of it.

expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

```
Expected: "validToken"

Number of calls: 0

  42 |     const verifyJwtTokenSpy = jest.spyOn(jwtHelper, "verifyJwtToken");
  43 |
> 44 |     expect(verifyJwtTokenSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('validToken');
     |                               ^
  45 |     expect(mockRes.status).toHaveBeenCalledWith(401);
  46 |     expect(mockRes.json).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
  47 |       error: 'Authentication Failed'

  at Object.<anonymous> (__tests__/unit/middlewares/auth.middleware.test.js:44:31)
```

In the `auth.middleware.js` file for implementing `isAuthenticatedUser` function, I checked if the header contains Bearer token, if yes then next thing I did was to check for the token format using regular expression. If these checks are passed then I tried to decode the data using `verifyJwtToken` function. Otherwise, I returned `401` error code.

```js
const { verifyJwtToken } = require('../helpers/jwt.helper');

const isAuthenticatedUser = function (req, res, next) {
  const token = req?.headers?.authorization?.startsWith('Bearer').split(' ')[1];

  if (!token) {
    return res.status(401).json({
      error: 'Authentication Failed',
    });
  }

  try {
    const jwtTokenPattern = /^Token\s[A-Za-z0-9-_=]+\.[A-Za-z0-9-_=]+\.?[A-Za-z0-9-_.+/=]*$/;

    const tokenFormatMatched = jwtTokenPattern.test(token);
    let rawToken = '';
    if (tokenFormatMatched) {
      rawToken = token.substr(token.indexOf(' ') + 1);

      const decodedData = verifyJwtToken(rawToken);
      req.user = decodedData;
      next();
    } else {
      return res.status(401).json({
        error: 'Authentication Failed',
      });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(401).json({
      error: 'Authentication Failed',
    });
  }
};
module.exports = { isAuthenticatedUser };
```

To test the code for `auth.middleware.js`, I tried to test two different scenarios. One with `missing authentication token` and another with `invalid token` error. But, actually I would also consider testing another additional scenario i.e, `token with proper format`.

```js
const { verifyJwtToken } = require("../../../helpers/jwt.helper");
const { isAuthenticatedUser } = require("../../../middlewares/auth.middleware");
const jwtHelper = require("../../../helpers/jwt.helper");
const mockRequest = () => {
  return {
    headers: {
      Authorization: "Bearer"
    }
  }
};

const mockResponse = () => {
  return {
    status: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    json: jest.fn().mockReturnThis()
  }
};

const mockNext = jest.fn();

describe("Unit tests for auth.middleware.js file", () => {

  it("Should check for missing authentication token error", () => {
    //Arrange
    const mockReq = mockRequest();
    const mockRes = mockResponse();
    //Act
    isAuthenticatedUser(mockReq, mockRes, mockNext);
    //Assert
    expect(mockRes.status).toHaveBeenCalledWith(401);
    expect(mockRes.json).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
      error: "Authentication Failed"
    });
    expect(mockNext).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
  it('should return a 401 error response when an error occurs when token is not valid', () => {
    const mockReq = mockRequest().headers = { Authorization: 'Bearer validtoken' };
    const mockRes = mockResponse();

    isAuthenticatedUser(mockReq, mockRes, mockNext);
    const verifyJwtTokenSpy = jest.spyOn(jwtHelper, "verifyJwtToken");

    expect(verifyJwtTokenSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('validToken');
    expect(mockRes.status).toHaveBeenCalledWith(401);
    expect(mockRes.json).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
      error: 'Authentication Failed'
    });
    expect(mockNext).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Comment: Your code has a lot of problems, but for your issue, you're calling `spyOn` *after* you run your function under test.

Comment: @possum, I called spyOn before calling function under test. Still, it didn't fix my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I was able to solve my issue by modifying my code and changed test cases accordingly. Below are updated codes for both of the files.

[file: auth.middleware.js]

```js
const { verifyJwtToken } = require('../helpers/jwt.helper');

const isAuthenticatedUser = function (req, res, next) {
  try {
    if (!req?.headers?.authorization?.startsWith('Bearer')) {
      return res.status(401).json({
        error: 'Authentication Failed',
      });
    }
    const token = req.headers.authorization?.split(' ')[1];
    if (!token) {
      return res.status(401).json({
        error: 'Authentication Failed',
      });
    }

    const decodedData = verifyJwtToken(token);
    req.user = decodedData;
    next();
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(401).json({
      error: 'Authentication Failed',
    });
  }
};
module.exports = { isAuthenticatedUser };
```

[file: auth.middleware.test.js]

```js
const { isAuthenticatedUser } = require("../../../middlewares/auth.middleware");
const mockRequest = () => {
  return {
    headers: {
      authorization: "Bearer"
    }
  }
};

const mockResponse = () => {
  return {
    status: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    json: jest.fn().mockReturnThis()
  }
};

const mockNext = jest.fn();

describe("Unit tests for auth.middleware.js file", () => {

  it("Should check for missing authentication token error", () => {
    //Arrange
    const mockReq = mockRequest().headers = { headers: {} };
    const mockRes = mockResponse();
    //Act
    isAuthenticatedUser(mockReq, mockRes, mockNext);
    //Assert
    expect(mockRes.status).toHaveBeenCalledWith(401);
    expect(mockRes.json).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
      error: "Authentication Failed"
    });
    expect(mockNext).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
  it("Should return a 401 error response when an error occurs when token is not valid", () => {
    //Arrange
    const mockReq = mockRequest().headers = { headers: { authorization: "Bearer validtoken" } };
    const mockRes = mockResponse();
    //Act
    isAuthenticatedUser(mockReq, mockRes, mockNext);
    //Assert
    expect(mockRes.status).toHaveBeenCalledWith(401);
    expect(mockRes.json).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
      error: 'Authentication Failed'
    });
    expect(mockNext).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
  it("Should return a 401 error when no authentication token is passed", async () => {
    //Arrange
    const mockReq = mockRequest();
    const mockRes = mockResponse();
    //Act
    isAuthenticatedUser(mockReq, mockRes, mockNext);
    //Assert
    expect(mockRes.status).toHaveBeenCalledWith(401);
    expect(mockRes.json).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
      error: "Authentication Failed"
    });
    expect(mockNext).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Now, all of my tests are passing. Also, it covers 100% of my codes.